Creating a grid with template areas
im trying to build a layout of colored blocks for an exercise but i dont see how to get it done. for now i have 6 rows of blocks the same size. however, the next div called violet i would want to be the full width and 4 rows as size. this is how i want it to be: 
Here is the html + css code right now. it should be done with grid template areas but i cant really manage how to use them the right way.


body, html {
    height: 100vh;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.container {
    width: 800px;
    height: 800px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
    gap: 15px;
}

.container div {
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.red {
    background-color: rgb(199, 48, 48);
}

.lightblue {
    background-color: rgb(55, 207, 245);
}

.lightgreen {
    background-color: greenyellow;
}

.blue {
    background-color: rgb(35, 35, 121);
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Grid</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Row 1 -->
        <div class="red"></div>
        <div class="red"></div>
        <div class="red"></div>
        <div class="red"></div>
        <!-- Row 2 -->
        <div class="lightgreen"></div>
        <div class="lightblue"></div>
        <div class="lightblue"></div>
        <div class="lightblue"></div>
        <!-- Row 3 -->
        <div class="lightgreen"></div>
        <div class="lightblue"></div>
        <div class="lightblue"></div>
        <div class="lightblue"></div>
        <!-- Row 4 -->
        <div class="lightgreen"></div>
        <div class="lightblue"></div>
        <div class="lightblue"></div>
        <div class="lightblue"></div>
        <!-- Row 5 -->
        <div class="lightgreen"></div>
        <div class="lightblue"></div>
        <div class="lightblue"></div>
        <div class="lightblue"></div>
        <!-- Row 6 -->
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div class="blue"></div>
        <div class="blue"></div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>



Anyone has an idea on how to get it done that involves it being built mainly by grid template areas? Would be appreciated!

grid-template-areas will require you to wrap each color section in it's own container and assign each container to it's own area. Frankly, grid-template-areas are not really optimal here. They are intended to lay out blocks of content, not individual bits of content. Oh, and not to complicate matters if you use grid-template-areas you would need subgrid and I don't think you want to go there yet.

What does ‘mainly by grid-template-areas’ mean? What are you not allowed to use? And what is the aspect ratio of those rectangles to be?

Do you really want to do it 'mainly' with grid template areas? It's messier (well, more verbose) than using other grid positioning methods given most of the elements will just naturally fall into place in sequence.

You can specify each grid element in its place using grid-template / grid-area.
Or you can simply "extend" div.purple with grid-column:


.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  gap: 12px;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.grid div {
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.lightblue {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.purple {
  background-color: purple;
  grid-column: span 4;
  grid-row: span 4;
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange;
}
<div class="grid">
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="lightblue"></div>
  <div class="lightblue"></div>
  <div class="lightblue"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="lightblue"></div>
  <div class="lightblue"></div>
  <div class="lightblue"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="lightblue"></div>
  <div class="lightblue"></div>
  <div class="lightblue"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="lightblue"></div>
  <div class="lightblue"></div>
  <div class="lightblue"></div>
  <div class="empty"></div>
  <div class="empty"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
  <div class="purple"></div>
  <div class="orange"></div>
  <div class="orange"></div>
  <div class="orange"></div>
  <div class="orange"></div>
</div>



